# how to pass a form input to a form in a modal (bootstrap/jquery)?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, variables, modal-dialog

I am having difficulties with something pretty basic... I have a for where the user inputs his email address,when he submits, I call a modal (using bootstrap/jquery). this modal contains another form where user is asked additional information. However, I do not know how to pass the email variable from the initital form to the form contained in the modal.

This is the initial form where I collect the email address:

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" class="form-inline" method="POST" id="register-init">
    <input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register" placeholder="Enter your email to get started" id="email-init" name="email" value="">
    <input class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register" value="Register">
    </form>
```

and this is the lines pertaining to the email address in the modal:

```
<dt><label for="email">Email Address</label>   

<dd><input id="email"> name="email" type="text" value="{{ request.form.email }}"></dd>
```

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: the code for the modal didnt work so here it is:                                                                                                                            <dt><label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <dd><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="{{ request.form.email }}">

  </dd>

Comment: You never reload the page right? If not, just take the input's value using the `val()` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. To be honest : I have near 0 knowledge of javascript /jquery... Would you have an example by any chance please? (I tried using val() but without the proper logic I don't end up with the right result... :( Thanks!

Comment: If you submit the form to an action as I can see, you can't do this with just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As I suck at programming says, just need to use the .val() method.
Like so:

```
$('#email').val($('#email-init').val());
```

Here's a working [JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/huvayapumo/edit?html,output).

The "magic" is done by the JS script at the end.
When you click on the button, the script copies the content of the **#email-init** textbox to **#email** textbox, thats all.

Comment: Dear David and "I suck at programming", thank you both for your input! David: I really appreciate you made the effort of making this working example for me :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, @choubix. :)